# Where is menu item in Joomla 1.5?

Tags: joomla, menu, navigation, content-management-system, version

OK, I'm new to Joomla.  Making updates for someone still using 1.5, plan to get them upgraded to v3...

I need to add a new article and menu item.  I've figured out where to do that in the backend, but my menu item isn't showing up in the navigation.  I went to menu manager, where I added the new link to a menu called mymenu.  I see the actual module in the template is titled myleftmenu, and I have the menu item selected there with the others from mymenu that appear throughout the site.

I've researched this and see maybe there were some bugs in 1.5, even some weird conflict with php 5.3, but none of this makes sense.  I don't have spaces or special characters in the menu alias (or wherever that had been an issue for some people).  I'm really stumped here because this really makes no sense.  I don't seem to have anywhere else to look in the backend to update or change this, so what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would check:

1- check if you are placing your mymenu in the right module position. To do that put that /index.php?tp=1 at the end of your url (eg: www.web.com/index.php?tp=1) it will give you the position.

2- check if your menu is published (you need to click on "published")

3- if you are trying to make a drop down menu : know that it is not supporter by native joomla so you need to download  module such as this [one](http://www.ari-soft.com/Joomla-Components/ARI-Ext-Menu/Detailed-product-flyer.html).

4- maybe your menu works but is not display because of overflow:hidden

Comment: I went through your suggestions and it looks like everything is in place and published.  No drop down menu and nothing in the CSS to hide the new menu item.  Think if I just update to Joomla 3 it will sort of fix itself?

Comment: are you sure you menu item is set to public? (not private/registred). Do you have your website's adress ? It should work under Joomla 1.5 (I never had this problem) and updating a website is a lot of work and may not solve the problem.

Comment: I should not be "public and/or published" but "public AND published" ! Are you trying to add the Calendar menu ? Did you try to change another menu item (for example on the menu item Police, just add 'of vernon', check on the website if it's changing anything and if yes, remove your edit. Your image is there : ../online/templates/vernon/images/menu.gif. To find out that you can use chrome console (on chrome, right click somewhere on the page and select inspect element). If you are using Firefox, you have to install firebug. Or simply right click, page info, media.

Comment: Can you send a printscreen of the menu manager of your mymenu  (with the menu item you want to add, and all the one already active). Thanks

Comment: I don't have access to it at the moment, but to clarify, the element I'm trying to add is definitely both public and published.

Comment: When you have acces, try to edit another menu in mymenu : just to make sure in , joomla is retrieving the menu from menu manager.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to modify other menu items in the backend and nothing was updating.  I finally went searching for a php file that could have been hand-coded and modified and found that in my modules directory.  Not being familiar with Joomla, and not sure if this menu had even been set up correctly, I then had to figure out how to get the right blog and item ID numbers for the hyperlink.  Ugh!  I feel like someone went about building this in a way that just made it more difficult for everyone who has to update the site in the future.  Now I'm really wondering what a version upgrade is going to do to this!